# ASP.NET - Asynchronous Web Service

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to asynchronously execute a web service from my ASP.NET web application. This particular web service (.asmx) belongs to the same project as my web application. I have noticed that when I reference the web service from another web application, I can call the web service asynchronously using the following code:

```
TestService service = new TestService();
service.TestMethod();
```

However, if I reference the web service via a separate web application, I notice that I have the option to execute it asynchronously using the following code:

```
ServiceProxy.TestService service = new ServiceProxy.TestService();        
service.TestMethodAsync();
```

The trick is, I want to asynchronously execute the web service from a web page that is in the same application as my web service. Is this possible? If so, how?

Is it possible to do this *without* putting my web service in a separate project?

Thank you,

Comment: The first code sample is an example of calling the method _synchronously_ from within the same project, right? Not asynchronously as the question states.

Comment: No, it's worse. See my answer.

Comment: I caught that the OP was using the WebService implementation class directly and not calling it as a web service, but my point was that the question as written calls that an asynchronous call, when it is clearly synchronous.

Comment: It will be interesting to see when he replies. "Web Service in Same Project" usually equals confusion, and not intent.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I recommend you put your web services into a separate project.

Second, when you called:

```
TestService service = new TestService();
service.TestMethod();
```

you were falling into a trap that you made possible because they were in the same project. You were calling the TestMethod directly. That's not a web service call, it's a direct call to the TestMethod.

I suggest you put the service into another project, then use a Web Reference or Service Reference to access it from your web application.

**EDIT**: you could keep it in the same application, but that will continue to be confusing. You must always use a web reference or service reference if you're calling it as a web service.

If it's part of the same application, then why is it a web service at all?

Answer (score 0):

It could still reference the same application as a web service, couldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the confusion, you should probably not be calling your web service method directly at all. Leave that method to be called by ASP.Net in response to a web method request.

You can, however, move the implementation of your web method into another class that can be instantiated and called by both the web service class and your web application at any other time. With that class in place, if you want to call one of its methods asynchronously, you should look at creating a delegate and using BeginInvoke() and EndInvoke().